# Do I need UDIDs for .ipa builds which are installed with iTunes

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes, ipa, ad-hoc-distribution

I want to distribute and adhoc build .ipa file which will be installed on the client's device by manually syncing the app with iTunes. I created the distribution profile and made the .ipa build.
My question is - do I need the client's device udid added for that provisioning profile? Will he be able to drag the .ipa build to his itunes app library, select the device, click install, sync and use the application?
Is there something wrong with this approach? Due to different reasons the other distribution options provided by apple do not work for me unfortunately.

Comment: if you are using enterprise provisioning profile then you do not need client's iOS device's UDID.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. [You need the UDIDs for Ad Hoc](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/12/23/creating-iphone-ad-hoc-distribution-builds.html). If you want to distribute without specifying the devices you need [the enterprise distribution](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/)

**EDIT**

The statement above is true, but it seems you're using iTunes Connect for Beta testing.

> There are three options to distribute your app for beta testing. Two
>   prerelease options are managed through iTunes Connect. You upload your
>   app to iTunes Connect using Xcode and then sign in to iTunes Connect
>   to **invite testers to download your app. Optionally, distribute your
>   app to 25 of your iTunes Connect users (with either Technical, Admin,
>   or Legal roles) or 1000 users specifying just email addresses**.
>   Distributing your app to users requires approval from App Review.

[documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html)

That means that **you don't have to specify all the devices in your provisioning file** beforehand. You only have to do that while distributing through Ad Hoc.

Comment: Hmm..It is true that I specified one udid when I created the provisioning profile but it was only to go to the next step of the profile wizard. Just now I was able to install the app to two different devices with iTunes sync. I repeat - the provisioning profile has none of the two UDIDs of the devices I just installed the app to.

Comment: Yes, basically what I did is - create new app id, create ad hoc distribution provisioning profile, add 1 udid(of a completely different device than the two I tested on), then in xcode i created a new empty project with that app id, exported and .ipa (adhoc distribution build), then opened iTunes app, drag that ipa to the applications, hook an ipad device and install(sync) the .ipa build to it. The app runs just fine and that device's id is not in the provisioning profile's devices list. iTunes version is 12.x and devices iOS version is 8.